# Alternative Curve Styles

Tags: cytoscape.js

Is it possible to import our own curve-style instead of the default cytoscape ones? e.g. `bezier`, `unbundled-bezier`, `haystack` etc.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can specify arbitrary straight line segments or curves.  Unless your line shape is somehow not in those two categories, the existing lines suffice.

Comment: I see, what I'm trying to achieve can be seen here [http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=b6f4mr&s=9#.Vrrwt1h96Um](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=b6f4mr&s=9#.Vrrwt1h96Um). I've had a look at svgjs and considered drawing the edge in a container on top of the cytoscape canvas. Does cytoscape allow extensions that can alter how the edge looks? Thanks.

Comment: You could try a white edge and a black shadow.  In general, edges are drawn with strokes -- and strokes don't have borders.